# Como encriptar e desencriptar dados em Swift 3 de formar nativa sem usar nenhuma lib externa

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho um serviço em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) que deve ser acessado com uma `url` encriptada.

Existe alguma forma de encriptar dados em **Swift** de forma nativa sem usar essas `lib` do Cocoapods?

Meu projeto não usa nada disso e gostaria de manter assim se for possivel.

Comment: Qual é a o algoritmo de encriptacao que está a usar? É um HMAC? É um AES? É um DES? (especifique qual é a implementacao)

Comment: Bruno obrigado pelo seu retorno, então este webapi c# usa MD5 mas se não houver nada nativo do Swift que faça encriptação em MD5 posso alterar o metodo do webapi, só não queria usar nenhum "lib" no meu projeto Swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32166735/2582714

Comment: Leonardo Cesar Teixeira obrigado, mas não existe nenhuma maneira de faz isso de forma nativa, sem ter que usar esses bibliotecas externas?????

Comment: @JulioFigueiredo No post que te mandei não está sendo usada nenhuma biblioteca de terceiro, e sim recursos nativos do iOS. https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CC_MD5.3cc.html

Comment: Leonardo Cesar Teixeira, legal consegui, sinceramente não sabia que podia ser feita essa "ponte" entre as linguagens, todas as pessoas que me falaram sobre isso disseram para mim usar alguma biblioteca externa. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso te ajuda?

```
let senhaMD5 = self.MD5(string: textField.text!)
let stringMD5 = senhaMD5.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()



func MD5(string: String) -> Data {
    let messageData = string.data(using:.utf8)!
    var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    _ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in
        messageData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
            CC_MD5(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }
    return digestData }
```